# Expand $\prod\limits_{i=1}^5\left[\bigcup_{j=1}^i A_i\right]$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^5\left[\prod\limits_{j=1}^i A_i\right]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^5\left[\bigcup_{j=1}^i A_i\right]$ in expanded form?

Is it $\prod\limits_{i=1}^5(A_1 \cup A_i)=(A_1 \cup A_1) \times (A_1 \cup A_2) \times (A_1 \cup A_3) \times (A_1 \cup A_4) \times (A_1 \cup A_5)$?

And would $\bigcup_{i=1}^5 \left[\prod\limits_{j=1}^i A_i \right] = \bigcup_{i=1}^5(A_1 \times A_i)=(A_1 \times A_1) \cup (A_1 \times A_2) \cup (A_1 \times A_3) \cup (A_1 \times A_4) \cup (A_1 \times A_5)$

Comment: Do you mean $\prod_{i=1}^5 [\bigcup_{j=1}^i A_j ]$ instead, so subscript $j$ in the inner term? Same for the second ?

Comment: No, it's $i$ in the subscript in the inner term

Comment: Then the inner terms are undefined.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma if j was in the subscript in the inner term what would the expanded form be?

Comment: The first would be $A_1 \times (A_1 \cup A_2) \times( A_1 \cup A_2  \cup A_3) \times  (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 ) \times  (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4  \cup A_5)$

Comment: The second the same with $\cup$ and $\times$ interchanged.